# Session.set() upon route event in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I have this functionality associated with clicking a button:

```
 'click .single-speaker-info a': function(ev, speaker){
    ev.preventDefault();
    Session.set('selectedDocId', this._id);
}
```

But I'd like it to happen upon hitting this route

```
Router.route('speaker', {
        path:'/speakers/:_id',
        template: 'speaker',
        data: function(){
            return Speakers.findOne(this.params._id);
        },

        //my attempted solution
        selectedDocId: function(){
            Session.set('selectedDocId', this._id);
        }
    });
```

But I can't find any documentation on how to execute a method on a route.

Here is the Template.helper Im using to `get` the property Im setting

```
       Template.speaker.helpers({

            editingDoc: function(){
                return Speakers.findOne({_id: Session.get('selectedDocId')});
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I can't find any documentation on how to execute a method on a route.

Iron Router offers a number of [hooks](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#available-hook-methods):

- onRun  <-- probably what you need
- onRerun
- onBeforeAction
- onAfterAction
- onStop

Answer (score 1):

You could use Template.x.rendered, once the page is rendered, any code in that block will be executed. Of course this would not be in your router.

In your case:

```
Template.speaker.rendered = function() {
    //Get data from router
    var data = Router.current().data();

    Session.set('selectedDocId', data._id);
}
```